# Converting atlaskit markdown notation to html elements

Tags: javascript, reactjs, markdown, jira, atlaskit

https://jira.atlassian.com/secure/WikiRendererHelpAction.jspa?section=all

https://atlaskit.atlassian.com/packages/editor/editor-markdown-transformer

I am trying to convert the below text as 'html' elements:-

```
    Regular, **Strong**, *Italic*, @Artur Bodera, ***Strong Italic***
    
    ---
    
    [Regular link](//atlassian.com), [**strong link**](//atlassian.com), [***strong italic link***](//atlassian.com)
    
    ---

!quicktime.mov|width=300,height=400!

{noformat}
preformatted piece of text
 so *no* further _formatting_ is done here
{noformat}
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/atlaskiteditor-markdown-transformer-0-markdown-transformer-forked-9q428

The provided codesandbox package is missing dependencies in provided example by markdown-transformer. How to fix this?

How to convert the above notation to corresponding HTML elements.

Comment: I do not clearly understand what you want help with. Do you want to convert something like `[text](uri)` in to `<a href="uri">text</a>`, or process only the markdown within the `[text]` part, or something else? Also note, the output of many tools _using_ markdown may not be pure HTML, but HTML+CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Showdown](https://github.com/showdownjs/showdown) to convert MD -> HTML, then parse the `@user`s yourself.

Comment: Showdown  do not converts (Advanced Formatting and Images and attachments and other jira markdown etc specific to jira) in correct html format.. It ignores width, height etc of markdown